# Unable convert a column from object to str

Tags: python, pandas

I am playing around with my amazon purchase history and trying to clean up the data. One of the problems that I am having is converting my columns from `object` to `string` then `float`. The reason why is because I want to remove the `$` from total money spent before I try to do any calculations. I tried something like this, but when I do `new_ap.dtype` it still list this column as an `Object`.

```
new_ap['money'] = new_ap['money'].astype('str')
new_ap = new_ap.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('$'))
new_ap['money'] = new_ap['money'].astype('float64')
```

[Picture to verify my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufiJ.png)

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your example works fine for me on a data frame with a single column containing only one row with the string `$123.123`.

Comment: added photo to show what is happening

Comment: You need to add your data as text rather than images.

Comment: I'd just extract the number `new_ap['money'].str.extract('(\d{2}.\d{2})'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing dollar and comma and then convert to float

```
new_ap['money'] = new_ap['money'].str.replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```